# How To Call The Index Of A Listview Outside Of Builder In Flutte

Tags: flutter, listview, indexing, audio-player

in my flutter application, I want to change the background color   of text in list items with the audio playing. each list item has an audio. The problem is I'm try to pass the list's item index outside the listview.builder to play-audio method but upon playing the playlist, only index no 5  is highlighted when the audio 2 starts. I have to detect when the audio ends and then make the next verse highlighted accordingly and play the next verse automatically. Here's the code;

```
 int highlightedIndex;
 int itemIndex=0;


 ListView.builder(
                            controller: hiding.controller,
                            itemCount: surahcountlist.length,
                            itemBuilder: (context, index) {

                             itemIndex= index;
                          return GestureDetector(

                             
                              child: Card(
                                  color: getColor(index, surahcountlist[index].surah_no,  surahcountlist[index].ayah_no),// light_mode ? Colors.white : Color(0xFF6D6D6D),
                                  child: Column(
                                      textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.start,
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                      CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                                      children: <Widget>[
                                        showBSMLSV(index),

                                        Wrap(
                                            direction: Axis.horizontal,
                                            alignment: WrapAlignment.start,
                                            runAlignment: WrapAlignment.center,
                                            textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
                                            spacing: 2.0,
                                            // gap between adjacent chips
                                            runSpacing: 5.0,
                                            children: makeSurahListview(
                                                surahcountlist[index].surah_no,
                                                surahcountlist[index].ayah_no,
                                                surahcountlist[index].count,
                                                index)),
                                      ])));

                     
                        }
                        ),

void playAudioNetwork(int index) async{

     Playlist playlist;

    List<Audio> _audios = [];

    for (int i =1;i<=7;i++) {

      String Url= 'https://everyayah.com/data/Ayman_Sowaid_64kbps/00100${i}.mp3';
      _audios.add(Audio.network(Url));
      print(Url);
    }
    playlist = Playlist(audios: _audios);
    audioPlayer.playlistAudioFinished.listen((event) {

      setState(() {
highlightedIndex = index;
      });
    });

    audioPlayer.open(
      playlist,
      autoStart: true,
      showNotification: true,
    );

  }
```

In bottom Navigation Bar:

```
SizedBox(
                              width: 45,
                              height: 45,
                              child: FloatingActionButton(
                                onPressed: () {

                                  playAudioNetwork(itemIndex);
                                },
                                backgroundColor: light_mode
                                    ? Color(0xFFEA80FC)
                                    : Color(0xFF6D6D6D),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.play_arrow,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  size: 30,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ),

TextSpan(
                      text: arabic  ,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: getTextColor(index),
                        backgroundColor:  highlightedIndex == index ? Colors.blue:Colors.white,
                        fontSize: 24.0,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.w200,
                        fontFamily: 'uthmanitext', ),
```

Answer (score 0):

Color getBackgroundColor (int index)
{
const availableColors =

[
Color.fromARGB(255, 170, 171, 168),

Color.fromARGB(255, 188, 122, 119),

Color.fromARGB(255, 205, 155, 157),

Color.fromARGB(255, 219, 199, 201),

Color.fromARGB(255, 136, 167, 149),

Color.fromARGB(255, 230, 192, 181),

Color.fromARGB(255, 184, 208, 228),
];

return availableColors[index % 7];
}